# Loop through specific ad users

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a problem with looping ad users.
I have a list of users who are or were in AD. The list contains about 800 entries (therefore not by hand)
The loop should return whether this user is still in AD or no longer exists

```
[string[]]$user = Get-Content -Path D:\Temp\user.txt    
for ($i=0;$i -le $user.Count; $i++){

    [bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter { "SamAccountName -eq '$user[$i]'" })
}
```

If I run this, the following error occurs:
[image: Error message]

If you could help, I would be very grateful

Comment: Please do not insert a screenshot of the error but paste the message into your question. Besides, are you sure your `-Filter` is working as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps easier is to reverse the logic and first get all user SamAccountNames in a Hashtable.

Then loop through the names from the text file and report if that name is found in the hashtable or not.

Something like:

```
# create a hashtable with SamAccountName as key. The value doesn't matter
$userHash = @{}
Get-ADUser -Filter * | ForEach-Object { $userHash[$_.SamAccountName] = $true }

# read the textfile to get an array of SamAccountNames to test
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\user.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'User'   = $_
        'Exists' = $userHash.ContainsKey($_)
    }
 }
```

If you like, you can save this to cssv file by appending `| Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\UserReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation` after the final curly closing bracket.

Output:

```
User     Exists
----     ------
Lauchix  True  
GoneAway False
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `-Filter` content.

```
  ...
  [bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter { "SamAccountName -eq '$($user[$i])'" })
  ...
```